# US National Map WMS fails to render in QGIS but displays fine in ArcGIS

Tags: qgis, wms

I am trying to display [this WMS from the USA National Map](https://www.mrlc.gov/geoserver/NLCD_Land_Cover/wms?SERVICE=WMS&REQUEST=GetCapabilities) in QGIS.  After adding the WMS connection in QGIS I can see the connection in the QGIS browser.  When I add the WMS to the QGIS to Layers the layer fails to render.  This holds true for QGIS v 3.22 and 3.28.

[image]

[image]

As a test I made the connection to the WMS in ArcGIS 10.7 and see that the data renders fine in ArcGIS but I have a co-worker who needs to use QGIS.

Oddly, these data will render if added to a new QGIS project (in the same CRS) but will not render if I add them to an existing project even when I remove all other layers from that project.

Why will this WMS not display in QGIS?

[image]

Comment: I added the url https://www.mrlc.gov/geoserver/ows?SERVICE=WMS&"/ that I found in the page you had a link to.  Then I added the layer NLCD_2019_Land_Cover_L48 and it displays as I would expect an NLCD layer would although the symbology in the TOC only shows a hatched blue.  I'm using  QGIS 3.28.6.

Comment: Tested in QGIS 3.30.3 and works as expected - possible bug in older versions?

Comment: Thanks for testing.  Did this work for you in a project that already has data?  Seems to work fine for me if and only if I add to a blank QGIS project despite the version of QGIS.

Comment: Blank project for me worked.

Comment: Probably a projection/scale issue, look in the network plugin and add the failing urls